# flex 3 datagrid and xmllistcollection

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, itemrenderers

im trying to display content of xmllistcollection in different fields in my datagrid however unless i use an itemrenderer the value is not displaying in the grid.

the xmllistcollection is populated from a webservice call. Inside my item renderer i use a custom namesspace to retrieve contents from the xmllistcollection

```
value.ns::firstName
```

however if i try something like dataField = "ns::firstName" in the datagrid without using an item renderer i get no data output.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `labelFunction` [property](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/dataGridClasses/DataGridColumn.html#labelFunction).

```
<mx:DataGrid dataProvider="{xml.ns::user}">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn labelFunction="nameLabelFunc" headerText="Name"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn labelFunction="ageLabelFunc" headerText="Age"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
<mx:XML source="data.xml" id="xml"/>
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridColumn;
        private var ns:Namespace = new Namespace("http://www.adobe.com");
        public function nameLabelFunc(item:Object, col:DataGridColumn):String
        {
            return item.ns::name;
        }
        public function ageLabelFunc(item:Object, col:DataGridColumn):String
        {
            return item.ns::age;
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
```

**data.xml**

```
<userInfo xmlns="http://www.adobe.com">
  <user>
    <name>John</name>
    <age>34</age>
  </user>
  <user>
    <name>Gessy</name>
    <age>32</age>
  </user>
</userInfo>
```